# Showing and adding text to a p element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to show a p element when a successful event has happened in my program. But i can only get the p element to appear but cannot get the text to show in the element, where am i going wrong?

```js
$('.success-msg').show().append('<strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been created');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="success-msg"></p>
```

The above code only shows the p element empty, How do i get the text to show?

Comment: the code works well ? what version of jquery you're using poste the whole used code heere ?

Comment: I tried it as well, and it works. Maybe, it could be the jQuery version.

Comment: Version 3.3.1 ?

Comment: Check console for error

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.success-msg').html('<strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been created').show();
```

Comment: using the `.text`, the **strong** element will literally be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the returned Promise using a $.when() statement

```
var show=function(){
    return $('.success-msg').show();
}
$.when(show()).done(function(){
    $('.success-msg').append('<strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been created');
});
```

Another way to solve it is

```
$('.success-msg').show(function(){
    $(this).append('<strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been created')
});
```

Another way to solve it is

```
$('.success-msg').html('<strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been created').show();
```

Your main mistake is that you put you script tag first so at the time of loading function there is no p with that class for that reason either you have to put script tag before end of body or encapsulated your code with in $(document).ready()

Comment: Sory, I can not understand your comment

Comment: The OP's code work in snippet but you posted new code

Comment: No the OP’s code in this way is not work he miss the difference between syncchronous and asynchronous so he will not find the idea of why his code is not work while he wrote it in a good way

Comment: This code brings back the same result as the original ?

Comment: i add two codes block now you have three you can check them if they are working or not then choose the one suitable for you

Comment: none of them work. They all bring back the P element without the text as with the original post. strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, thus I don't suggest new ways.

But, wrap your code in `document.ready`. It is possible that the `p` element is visible always and showing it is not because your code. Code below is full and testable without any changes:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p class="success-msg"></p>
 <script>
     $(function() {
        $('.success-msg').show().append/*or .html(..) or .append($("<strong ..."))*/('<strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been created');
      });
</script>
```

Check your wrapped code [online](https://jsbin.com/cuhivaxime/edit?output)